# Where is the installation download for Subsonic 2.2?

Tags: subsonic

Anyone know why I can't download the subsonic website development tool install anymore?

It only shows a source download.  Does anyone have a link to a full install download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh he's back - Eric's going to work up his installer. Maybe next week.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest 2.1 release. Then download the 2.2 zip and copy the files over the 2.1 installation.

The reason you can't get a 2.2 install is because the developer that used to contribute that to the project, took a hiatus from contributing. Although there's a rumor he's back, so it may happen eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the correct download location. Thanks for all the help.
http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/  Looks like it has moved over to google code.